# Can't install Heroku on Mac, it says Apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: heroku, installation

I downloaded Heroku from their web but couldn't install it. "heroku.pkg can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software. This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information."

I also tried in Terminal: $ brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku, but it says "bash: brew: command not found".

Then I wrote a ticket on Heroku Support but one of their drop-down menus didn't work, so I couldn't submit the ticket.

Very bad experience.

Comment: If `brew: command not found` did you consider [installing Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click with the right button in the application.
Next, click in open!

NOTE: Don't make double click!
[image: 1]

Comment: Thank you. I think it's working now. Could you explain what's the difference, please?